# How to show the data of a textfield to the label of a tableview cell?

Tags: objective-c

I am new to iOS developing. I am building a project where I want to show the text of a textfield of a view controller to the label of a table view cell of another viewcontroller. Can anyone tell me just the logic how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't posted any code, I will try to explain it to you.

You will have to create event for button, and there you can do something like `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegue" sender:self];`

Next thing is to create property in your new ViewController that will accept your value.

After that, in your `prepareForSegue` you can do `NSString *text = [self.textField text];`, get your new VC from `segue.destinationViewController;` and assign your value there.

So, in the end you will have :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if(segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourSegue"])
    {
        YourViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.accpetValue = [self.yourTextField text];
    }
}
```

and in your action for button:

```
- (IBAction)yourButton_pressed:(id)sender 
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegue" sender:self];
}
```

If you have tableViewController there, and you want to assign this value to the cell on the same screen, on button you can obtain the value with same way as above, and in you cellAtIndexPath you can do the following:

```
if(self.yourTextBox && [self.yourTextBox  text] && ![[self.yourTextBox text] isEqualToString:@""])
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.yourTextBox text];
}
else 
{
//something else
}
```

And on your button event you can do

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the view controller with the cell is open from the view controller with the textfield, is quite easy.

You can create a property NSString in the second view controller .h and then you can call it when you open this from the first.

```
 SecondViewController * cotroller = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
 controller.string = [textField text];
 [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:^{
 }]
```